# Return back from edit form after several updates in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to add functionality to my edit form. Perhaps not a best practice but...

I want to keep the original url for several updates. When a user first lands on edit form (from list or single view) I want a Cancel button that redirects user back to.. "referrer". After an update I redirect back to edit form with success message. I want to hide the Cancel button and show Back button. User can edit multiple times.

I tried to pass the original url through Request, but that didn't end well. Now I'm trying with storing the url in session. Ifs work, but the session item value gets overwritten in second iteration.

Perhaps I'm using the session the wrong way? Any idea? Perhaps another "better" way?

The code in my edit.blade

```
@if(url()->current() != URL::previous())
    @if(Session::has('myreferrer'))
        {{ Session::forget('myreferrer') }}
    @endif
    {{ Session::put('myreferrer', URL::previous()) }}
    <a href="{{ URL::previous() }}" class="btn">Cancel</a>
@else
<a href="{{ Session::pull('myreferrer') }}" class="btn">Back</a>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Session::pull()` fetches the value from the session *and removes it*. This is why the page doesn't work the second time:

1. User visits *edit* from *previous*

   - `URL::current() != URL::previous()`
   - `'myreferrer'` set to *previous*
   - Show *Cancel* button
2. User fills and saves *edit* form

   - `URL::current() === URL::previous()`
   - `'myreferrer'` set to `null` (because `Session::pull()`)
   - Show *Back* button
3. User saves *edit* form again

   - `URL::current()` *still* `=== URL::previous()`
   - `'myreferrer'` is *still* `null`
   - Show *Back* button again with an empty URL (because `'myreferrer'` is `null`) which the browser interprets as the current URL

We can use `Session::get()` to fetch the value *and* leave it in the session, but this pollutes the session because `'myreferrer'` still exists when the user navigates away from the *edit* form.

More importantly, this logic doesn't belong in a view template. Instead we'll use the controller to pass the value of `'myreferrer'` using a hidden input field:

```
public function edit($id) 
{
    // fetch data...

    return view('edit') 
        // if "myreferrer" isn't in the session yet, use previous URL:
        ->with('myreferrer', Session::get('myreferrer', URL::previous()));
}

public function update(Request $request) 
{
    // save data...

    return back()
        ->with('success', 'Your success message.') 
        // "flashes" to the session only for the next page load:
        ->with('myreferrer', $request->get('myreferrer'));
}

<form ...>
    <input type="hidden" name="myreferrer" value="{{ $myreferrer }}"/>
    ... 
    @if (Session::has('success')) 
        <a href="{{ $myreferrer }}" class="btn">Back</a>
    @else 
        <a href="{{ $myreferrer }}" class="btn">Cancel</a>
    @endif
```

I'm assuming you actually need the *previous* URL to be dynamic, such as if the user can open the *edit* form from different pages. [Named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes) offer better semantics when you don't need this flexibility.

For the sake of learning, here are some other pointers related to your code:

- We don't need `Session::has()` before `Session::forget()` (`forget()` skips if the key doesn't exist). Additionally, the call to `Session::put()` afterward overwrites the value here anyway, so we can remove the whole `@if(Session::has('myreferrer'))` block.
- `url()->` and `URL::` do the same thing. We should probably choose one for consistency.

Comment: Thank you for your great and extensive answer. I did try with hidden input first, but completely overlooked that I can set the url in edit function... Your solution works great. And yes I need a dynamic URL. One thing still bothers me. In my case the `'myreferrer'` was not set to `null` in second iteration. Instead I got the previous url pointing to edit form. As if it was set in every iteration.Thats why I started overcomplicating things I guess :)

Comment: Here's my theory: if the browser sees `<a href="">...</a>` (an empty `href`), it falls back to using the *current* URL as the address for the link. `'myreferrer'` was `null`, which left the empty `href`, but from the browser, it looked like it actually contained a the URL to the edit form.

Comment: I tried with var_dump session and 'myreferrer' was set to current url. So I'm guessing there is a "fallback" in the session itself. Anyway I won't use the logic in blade :)